# Flask app with jinja rendering; Does not auto refresh webpage

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

I have a Flask app that queries a database, and renders a table using the retrieved data using a jinja template. I would like the web page to continue refreshing periodically after the first click so that if the data in the database changes, the webpage displays the new data.

I have tried many things that other people have suggested on the net, but nothing seems to work. Here is a sample of what I tried:

1) Placing the following code in the jinja template file:

```
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
</head>
```

2) Placing the following code in the jinja template file:

```
<head>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function TimedRefresh( t ) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="JavaScript:TimedRefresh(2000);">
<p>Auto Refreshing Every 30 Seconds.</p>
</body>
```

3) placing the following code in the jinja template file:

```
<head>
<script TYPE="text/javascript">
var datetime = null,
    date = null;

var update = function () {
    date = moment(new Date())
    datetime.html(date.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'));
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    datetime = $('#datetime')
    update();
    setInterval(update, 1000);
});
</script>
</head>
```

..and

```
<div id="datetime"></div>
```

etc..

Nothing worked. The page is dead as a door knob -- loads the first time, but does not auto-refresh unless I press a button.
I am really puzzled. Would appreciate any help.
Any kind of refreshing is fine -- does not need to be in sections.
Please help.

Thank you,
neela.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy paste the code *below* `{% block page_content %}` line and *above* `<style>` line in your template file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timer = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(); }, 1500);
};
timer();
</script>
```

This is how your file should look: http://pastebin.com/G5tFxeA2

Note: This way to refresh table data is an extremely bad technique. You most likely want to query the table data using an API and redraw all the fields.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I tried this, and it doesn't work. I have the following line on the page with a random number generator which I put in there to test if the page is updating or not. And it does not update.           <th>Some text and  {{ range(1, 51) | random }}</th>

Comment: @neela `range()` is a generator function, use this instead to generate a random number instead `{{ 51 | random }}`. Also post the console log if any.

Comment: @MitestNinja if I change the code to {{ 51 | random }}, I get the following error:     <th>Tradeid  {{ 51 | random }}</th>
  File "/home/server/projects/flasky/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/filters.py", line 367, in do_random
    return choice(seq)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 273, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

Comment: The purpose of the random number generator is just to test if the page is reloading. The view.py function that originally renders the page makes database calls etc -- I am hoping that all those will rerun every minute or so if I can simply refresh the page.

Comment: @neela with `{{ range(1, 51) | random }}` can you post the console output you see in browser? Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: i am using firefox. this is the browser output:  Tradeid 35  Initiation date  Sell Amou nt  Buy Amount  Sell Symbol  Buy Symbol
5  2016-06-14  10,000  10,000  BND US EQUITY  JNK US EQUITY
6  2016-06-14  10,000  10,000  BND US EQUITY  SPY US EQUITY
7  2016-06-14  10,000  10,000  EEM US EQUITY  BND US EQUITY
8  2016-06-14  10,000  10,000  SPY US EQUITY  EEM US EQUITY
9  2016-06-14  10,000  10,000  JNK US EQUITY  QQQ US EQUITY
10  2016-06-14  10,000  10,000  BND US EQUITY  JNK US EQUITY

Comment: The above is formatted as a table. Is there a better way to post this output? I am an infrequent poster here ..

Comment: @neela I'm asking you to check the browser debugger console, opened using `F12`. It will show javascript errors. If not, can you post the complete source code of your template file on http://pastebin.com ?

Comment: Here is the full template code:  http://pastebin.com/YGWZcZ1m. There are no problems with the console output with {{range(1,51) | random}}. Just that it doesn't refresh. Here it is.

Comment: (flask)server@server-VirtualBox:~/projects/flasky$ gunicorn manage:app
[2016-06-18 14:16:16 +0000] [7594] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-06-18 14:16:16 +0000] [7594] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (7594)
[2016-06-18 14:16:16 +0000] [7594] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-06-18 14:16:16 +0000] [7616] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7616
[2016-06-18 14:16:46 +0000] [7594] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7616)
[2016-06-18 14:16:46 +0000] [7616] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7616)
[2016-06-18 14:16:46 +0000] [7636] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7636

Comment: [2016-06-18 14:17:16 +0000] [7594] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:7636)
[2016-06-18 14:17:16 +0000] [7636] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7636)
[2016-06-18 14:17:17 +0000] [7685] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7685
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
WARNING in views [/home/server/projects/flasky/app/main/views.py:22]:

Comment: Slow query: SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.email AS users_email, users.username AS users_username, users.role_id AS users_role_id, users.password_hash AS users_password_hash, users.confirmed AS users_confirmed, users.name AS users_name, users.location AS users_location, users.about_me AS users_about_me, users.member_since AS users_member_since, users.last_seen AS users_last_seen, users.avatar_hash AS users_avatar_hash 
FROM users 
WHERE users.id = %s
Parameters: (1,)
Duration: 1.899036s
Context: /home/server/projects/flasky/app/models.py:307 (load_user)

Comment: @neela You're posting the flask output. I was asking for 'browser console output'. Nevermind that. I've edited my answer, doing that should fix everything, hopefully.

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. An added benefit for me -- I just learned that there is something called a browser console :-). And I've used pastebin for the first time in life.

Comment: @neela Welcome. Please don't forget to mark this as an answer :)